# Testing if a number goes evenly into 6?

Tags: c, modulo

I am trying to see if two input numbers (integers) including negative numbers go into 6 evenly (remainder is 0). This is the code I was trying.

```
if((in1)%6 == 0 && (in2)%6 == 0){
    printf("Divisible: both\n");
}
else if((in1)%6 == 0 && (in2)%6 > 0){
    printf("Divisible: only %i\n",in1);
}
else if((in1)%6 > 0 && (in2)%6 == 0){
    printf("Divisible: only %i\n",in2);
}
else{
    printf("Divisible: neither\n");}
```

This works for all positive integer but for any negatives the printed code is always "Divisible: neither" any help as to how I can show both positive and negative numbers divisible by six with a remainder of 0 would be really helpful

Comment: See also: fizz buzz!

Comment: You need to be able to debug your code in order to become a competent software developer - unless you, unlike the rest of us, are always going to write error-free code that runs correctly the first time. I suggest that you add some code before the first `if` statement to print out the values of `in1`, `in2`, `in1 % 6` and `in2 % 6` in order to figure out what's going on. Best of luck.

Comment: @M.M - I think you meant [fizz buzz](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58615/1-2-fizz-4-buzz)

Comment: [Modulo of a negative number](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/519845/398889) on the Math Stack Exchange may explain some of what you are observing. Also see [Modulo operation with negative numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11720656/608639) and [modulo operation on negative numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30199474/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `!= 0` instead of `> 0`.  In C, `%` of negative number will give a negative result (or zero).

This is because `a / b` is defined as truncation-towards-zero since C99 (in C90 it was implementation-defined).  And `a % b` is defined as `a - (a / b) * b`.

Note that you actually do not need this test at all; you can rely on the behaviour of `if...else` not entering the `else` case if the `if` case was satisfied, e.g.:

```
if ( in1 % 6 == 0 && in2 % 6 == 0 )
{
    // ...
}
else if ( in1 % 6 == 0 )   
{
    // would not reach here if in2 % 6 == 0
}
else if ( in2 % 6 == 0 )
{
    // would not reach here if in1 % 6 == 0
}
else
```

Answer (score 0):

Another consideration, rather than oblige code to test numbers 3 times, re-write to perform only 2 test on the numnbers.

```
if (in1 % 6) {
  if (in2 % 6) {
    printf("Divisible: both\n");
  } else {
    printf("Divisible: only %i\n",in1);
  }
} else {
  if (in2 % 6) {
    printf("Divisible: only %i\n",in2);
  } else {
    printf("Divisible: neither\n");}
  }
}
```